# Electron - can't use file js

Tags: javascript, electron

i try to do an application, but my javascript file is not used, because i don't see the log.
i need to do something more than the "quick start" off electron ?

==============================index.html================================

```
<!-- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP -->


Sauvegarde de Manga




  <h1>Sauvegarde de Manga</h1>
  
  
  


  
    <p>Titre</p>
    <p>Commentaire</p>
    <p>Note</p>
    <p>Lien</p>
    <p>Dernier episode vu</p>
  
  <div class="tableau">
    <input type="text"  value="" id="titre">
    <input type="text"  value="" id="commentaire">
    <select name="cars" id="note">
      <option value="0">0</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
      <option value="11">11</option>
      <option value="12">12</option>
      <option value="13">13</option>
      <option value="14">14</option>
      <option value="15">15</option>
      <option value="16">16</option>
      <option value="17">17</option>
      <option value="18">18</option>
      <option value="19">19</option>
      <option value="20">20</option>

    </select>
    <input type="text"  value="" id="ln">
    <input type="text"  value="" id="epvu">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="stock">
  <div class="manga">
    <p>Titre</p>
    <p>Commentaire</p>
    <p>Note</p>
    <input type="submit"value="Regarder" id="lien">
    <p>Dernier episode vu</p>
    <div class="modif">
      <input type="submit" value="M" class="bElement util">
      <input type="submit" value="S" class="bElement util">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="manga">
    <p>Titre 2</p>
    <p>Commentaire 2</p>
    <p>Note 2</p>
    <input type="submit"value="Regarder" id="lien" class="bElement">
    <p>Dernier episode vu 2</p>
    <div class="modif">
      <input type="submit" value="M" id="modifier" class="bElement util">
      <input type="submit" value="S" id="supprimer" class="bElement util">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

===========================main.js===================================
`// Modules to control application life and create native browser window const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron') const path = require('path')`

`const createWindow = () => {`
`// Create the browser window.`
`const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({`
`width: 800,`
`height: 600,`
`webPreferences: {`
`preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')`
`}`
`})`

`// and load the index.html of the app.`
`mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')`

`// Open the DevTools.`
`// mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()`
`}`

`// This method will be called when Electron has finished`
`// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.`
`// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.`
`app.whenReady().then(() => {`
`createWindow()`

`app.on('activate', () => {`
`// On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the`
`// dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.`
`if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()`
`})`
`})`

`// Quit when all windows are closed, except on macOS. There, it's common`
`// for applications and their menu bar to stay active until the user quits`
`// explicitly with Cmd + Q.`
`app.on('window-all-closed', () => {`
`if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()`
`})`

`// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process`
`// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.`

`/*`
`lancer : npm run start`
`Pour avoir un executable : npm i electron-packager --save-dev`
`electron-packager .`
`*/`

`console.log('index');`
`===========================other.js===================================`
`console.log('main');`
`let retour = document.querySelector('#retour');`
`let ajout = document.querySelector('#ajouter');`
`let liste = document.querySelector('#liste');`
`bindRedirection(retour,'index.html');`
`bindAjout(ajout);`
`bindListe(liste);`

`let texttitre = document.querySelector('#titre');`
`let textcommentaire = document.querySelector('#commentaire');`
`let select = document.querySelector('#note');`
`let textln = document.querySelector('#ln');`
`let textepvu = document.querySelector('#epvu');`

`let tabelem = [texttitre,textcommentaire,select,textln,textepvu];`
`bindInput(texttitre, tabelem);`
`bindInput(textcommentaire, tabelem);`
`bindInput(textln, tabelem);`
`bindInput(textepvu, tabelem);`

[image: the result but i should have 'main' print after index]

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You trimmed too much. It looks like you are having problems with editing the code into the question properly. This should help: the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: i've done, but my probleme is a very little probleme i think, my file javascript other.js just not launch.

Comment: sorry i don't understand how the post work, it rollback ...